# Missing SSRS Web Services Directory

Tags: reporting-services, 2013

So the SQL Reporting Services Service Application is running, but from Central Administration, when I click on the service, then click "System Settings", it returns an error.

Digging through correlation IDs, I found that the Web Service was returning:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>
> Error Code: 0x80070003
>
> Config Error: Cannot read configuration file
>
> Config File: \?\C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\WebServices\Reporting\web.config

I go to the directory to check permissions on the folder, only to find it doesn't exist, though I've also confirmed in IIS that the virtual directory application is pointed there.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the SSRS SharePoint Add-In from the SQL disc to no avail.

***Additional Details**
Windows 2012 Datacenter, SQL 2012 Enterprise SP1, SharePoint 2013 Enterprise*

Comment: Confirmed that everything in the SQL 2012 SP1 rssharepoint.msi installer from the "Web Server Extensions" is installed, though there is nothing in the MSI in /WebServices/ - not sure if that's supposed to be handled by an HttpModule?

Comment: Did you install ssrs following this guide? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219068.aspx if so I will be running through it this weekend.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to follow that guide except that there are a few differences. It looks like they didn't officially support SharePoint 2013 until SQL 2012 SP1 - which there's not a whole lot of documentation for. Tried to make as much sense of it as possible. I started over from scratch and am still getting the same result, although it doesn't appear specific to SSRS - it looks like there's quite a few of the WCF services failing to work properly with variants of the same error.

Comment: Hi lukiffer, we set this up over the weekend and we had no issues. We used the same software as you for our experiment, except perhaps each part for us was on a separate box? Was yours all on one box? Maybe it's worth checking your KB updates for issues. Maybe you have to re-setup IIS and SharePoint, after totally removing them.

Comment: Wait I just looked our SQL Server 2012 is SP1 CTP3, this is REQUIRED. This isn't your issue is it?

Comment: SP1 went RTM week before last I believe - that's what we are using.

Comment: Put a ticket in with Microsoft. RTM should include what was in the CTP3 and the previous. You would of thought.

Comment: @lukiffer, have you found a solution/workaround for missing directory problem? I'm facing same issue with SP 2013 RTM and SQL 2012 Ent RTM

Comment: @usmanshaheen - We were able to get this to work. It appears it was a problem with the SQL SP1 installer wasn't correctly updating the SharePoint component - I've posted details below as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to get the RS component to successfully install by extracting the `RSSharePoint.msi` package from the SQL 2012 SP1 redistributable and using msiexec manually to install the package on each of the servers. The SSRS instance was unchanged, and once we had the SP1 SSRS SharePoint component installed on each of the WFEs, it worked fine - I'm assuming there's a problem with the SP1 installer.

Comment: Do you have any details on how you did this? We have the exact same issue with 2014

Answer (score 0):

Pull up the windows log for this event and it will tell you what was wrong with your web.config file. Fix the file and it will work.

This error is common on migrations in 2010 not seen it yet on 2013. It is usually a missing section of the web.config.

Comment: The web.config file doesn't exist - the parent directory `Reporting` under `WebServices` doesn't exist. As though it wasn't installed.

Comment: re: Migrations, this is a fresh install.

Comment: Throwing it at a sysadmin who may have another idea then. *tweeted*